# Summing and Gathering elements of array element-wise in MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

After doing calculations to multiply a matrix with a vector using Cartesian topology. I got the following process with the their ranks and vectors.

```
P0 (process with rank = 0) =[2 , 9].
P1 (process with rank = 1) =[2 , 3]
P2 (process with rank = 2) =[1 , 9] 
P3 (process with rank = 3) =[4 , 6].
```

Now. I need to sum the elements of the even rank processes and the odd ones separately, like this:

temp1 = [3 , 18]
 temp2 = [6 , 9]

and then , gather the results in a different vector, like this:

> result = [3 , 18 , 6 , 9]

My attampt to do it is to use the MPI_Reduce and then MPI_Gather like this :

```
// Previous code 
 double* temp1 , *temp2;
    if(myrank %2 == 0){
     BOOLEAN flag =  Allocate_vector(&temp1 ,local_m); // function to allocate space for vectors
     MPI_Reduce(local_y, temp1, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0 ,  comm);
     MPI_Gather(temp1, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, gResult, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE,0, comm);
      free(temp1);
         }
  else{
      Allocate_vector(&temp2 ,local_m);
      MPI_Reduce(local_y, temp2, local_n , MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0 ,  comm);
      MPI_Gather(temp2, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, gResult, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,comm);
      free(temp2);
         }
```

But the answer is not correct.It seemd that the code sums all elements of the even and odd process togather and then gives a segmentation fault error:
Wrong_result = [21 15 0 0]
 and this error

> ** Error in `./test': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000013c7510 ***
>   *** Error in`./test': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001605b60 ***

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the way you are trying to do it. To perform reduction over the elements of a subset of processes, you have to create a subcommunicator for them. In your case, the odd and the even processes share the same `comm`, therefore the operations are not over the two separate groups of processes but rather over the combined group.

You should use `MPI_Comm_split` to perform a split, perform the reduction using the two new subcommunicators, and finally have rank 0 in each subcommunicator (let's call those *leaders*) participate in the gather over another subcommunicator that contains those two only:

```
// Make sure rank is set accordingly

MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

// Split even and odd ranks in separate subcommunicators

MPI_Comm subcomm;
MPI_Comm_split(comm, rank % 2, 0, &subcomm);

// Perform the reduction in each separate group

double *temp;
Allocate_vector(&temp, local_n);
MPI_Reduce(local_y, temp, local_n , MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, subcomm);

// Find out our rank in subcomm

int subrank;
MPI_Comm_rank(subcomm, &subrank);

// At this point, we no longer need subcomm. Free it and reuse the variable.

MPI_Comm_free(&subcomm);

// Separate both group leaders (rank 0) into their own subcommunicator

MPI_Comm_split(comm, subrank == 0 ? 0 : MPI_UNDEFINED, 0, &subcomm);
if (subcomm != MPI_COMM_NULL) {
  MPI_Gather(temp, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, gResult, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, subcomm);
  MPI_Comm_free(&subcomm);
}

// Free resources

free(temp);
```

The result will be in `gResult` of rank 0 in the latter `subcomm`, which happens to be rank 0 in `comm` because of the way the splits are performed.

Not as simple as expected, I guess, but that is the price of having convenient collective operations in MPI.

---

On a side node, in the code shown you are allocating `temp1` and `temp2` to be of length `local_m`, while in all collective calls the length is specified as `local_n`. If it happens that `local_n > local_m`, then heap corruption will occur.

Comment: Thanks.The I applied your suggestions. The code run successfully first and then when I tried to run it again still gives the answer but with this error : Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_free: Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_free: Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_free(143): MPI_Comm_free(comm=0x7ffe22d63200) failed
PMPI_Comm_free(93).: Null communicator
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_free: Invalid communicator, error stack:PMPI_Comm_free(143): MPI_Comm_free(comm=0x7ffca17bd180) failed PMPI_Comm_free(93).: Null communicator

Comment: It seems that it can not create the communicator of the first line because it returns MPI_COMM_NULL

Comment: Ah, of course. my mistake. Processes should check if they are part of `subcomm` before trying to free it at the end. Fixed.

Comment: If you intend to call this sequence multiple times, then it makes sense to actually retain the two subcommunicators and only free them at the very end.